# Updating Jframe based on JLabel Click

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener

I am currently making a "Super Tic-Tac-Toe" application in Java. Here is a description of what I am aiming for. http://mathwithbaddrawings.com/ultimate-tic-tac-toe-original-post.  However I am having problems updating the Jframe on click.  My application is made of individual cells (JLabels) that make up the Tic-Tac-Toe boards (JPanels) which will reside in a JFrame.

My problem is that using *getSource* on MouseClick will only get me as seep as my JPanel, and I cannot access which cell of the tic-tac-toe grid was pressed.  Is there a way to check which one is pressed with my current method of organizing this project?

Here is My Code for viewing a ticTacToe Board that contains the listener:

```
public class TicTacToeView extends JPanel {
    public CellView[][] cv;
    public TicTacToe ttt;
    public TicTacToeView(TicTacToe t) {
        int rows = 3;
        int columns = 3;
        cv = new CellView[3][3];
        ttt = t;

        setSize(3 * 64, 3 * 64);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, columns));
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j ++) {
                System.out.println(ttt.getCellAt(i, j).toString());
                cv[i][j] = new CellView(ttt.getCellAt(i, j));
                cv[i][j].addMouseListener(new yourListener());
                add(cv[i][j]);
            }
        }

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ttt.toString();
    }

    public class yourListener extends MouseAdapter{ 
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

            CellView labelReference=(CellView)e.getSource();
            Cell cellClicked = labelReference.getCell();

            System.out.println(cellClicked.getCol() +"," + cellClicked.getRow());
            cellClicked.setState(CellState.O);
            ttt.setCellAt(cellClicked.getCol(), cellClicked.getRow(), CellState.O);
            System.out.println(ttt.toString());

       }
    }
}
```

Right now when i System.out it changes the correct cell to O as expected.  But I don't know how I would update the frame from here as the gameFrame is made out of this.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: The answer will depend on what you've attached the `MouseListener` to, from the sounds of it, they should be attached to the labels individually

Comment: @NabeelOmer Is that code good or should I include the code that contains the JLabel and the JFrame?

Comment: I guess this will be fine...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added the code to the OP that contains the Listener.  I can change the Board's state fine, but I cannot figure out how to change the top level graphics.

Comment: Earlier you said you couldn't figure out which label was pressed!

Comment: What's `CellView`? Given that you have a reference to `CellView` from the `MouseEvent` and a 2d array of `CellView`s you could simply loop through the 2d array until you find a match, at least it will tell you which row/column the cells in...

Comment: @NabeelOmer That was before I took your advice and switched the location of the listener to the Labels.  Now I cannot update the Frame from where I am processing the click.

Comment: @MadProgrammer My problem is in telling the Frame to update that cell.  Sorry that my explanation is unclear.

Comment: I assume your `setState` method should call `revalidate` and `repaint`

Comment: @MadProgrammer That was it!  I was setting it in a way that was kindof backtracking but now I got it.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, stop using a separate class for the `MouseListener`, this is the source of your problem. Directly add a mouse listener to `cv[i][j]`. You will be able to update your frame because now the mouse listener is also in the same class.

Cheers.

Comment: You mean put the listener in the class that the cv array is of?

Comment: @RyanStaurt No. I mean to say: `cv[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseListener());`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way the OP has the `MouseListener` set up, as it reduces the complexity and isolates responsibility.  In fact, the OP could be passing information to the listener when it's constructed to make it easier to do other things (like the row/column for instance, but I'd be passing that to the `CellView` if it was really needed)

Comment: That is one way of doing the job, using a constructor,I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is in telling the Frame to update that cell. Sorry that my explanation is unclear.

While there are ways to find the frame from the `CellView`, it's not required, instead, when `CellView#setState` is called, it should be calling `revalidate` and `repaint` on itself